# How to split an array in uneven batches in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to split an array into batches of 500, but I want to cover the case where the array size is not evenly divided by 500 as well. For example:

```
Array = [1,...,1100]
subArray1 = [1..500]
subArray2 = [500..1000]
subArray3 = [1000..1100]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
my @array = [prepopulated];
my $array_size = scalar(@array);
my $start = 0;
my $end = 500;

while ($start < $array_size) {
    my @subArray = @array[$start..$end];
    print Dumper(\@subArray);
    $start = $end;
    if($end + 500 > $array_size) {
        $end = $start + ($array_size % 500);
    } else {
        $end += 500;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but is there a better way to do this or does this break for some case I am not seeing?

Comment: Why? Seems like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @shawnhcorey I was more looking for cases this could break in.

Comment: I don't follow. Why do you want to batch them? What benefit do you hope for over simply iterating over the array one at a time?

Comment: @shawnhcorey because the algorithm of the batching is being used for some other purpose. In this example I replaced it with printing because what the batches are being used for didn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List::MoreUtils` covers exactly this kind of task:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(natatime);

my @Array = (1..1100);
my $it = natatime 500, @Array;
while (my @vals = $it->()) {
    printf "%d\n", 0+@vals;
}
```

---

```
500
500
100
```

No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 5):

I think [`splice`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) would be simpler and cleaner:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (1 .. 1100);
my $batch_size = 500;

while (@array) {
    my @batch = splice(@array, 0, $batch_size);
    # ...
}
```

Comment: As long as you are ok with the original array being emptied

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that perl's [range](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) operator `start..end` is inclusive both sides. `0..500` gives you: `0, 1, ..., 499, 500`

Assuming you don't want to duplicate boundary elements (e.g. index 500 included in two sub arrays), try the following.

Summary:

- change `$end` initialization to `499`
- inside the loop set `$start = $end+1`
- when checking if the new end is overflowing use `>=` instead: `$end + 500 >= $array_size`

code

```
my @array = [prepopulated];
my $array_size = scalar(@array);
my $start = 0;
my $end = 499;

while ($start < $array_size) {
    my @subArray = @array[$start..$end];
    print Dumper(\@subArray);
    $start = $end+1;
    if($end + 500 >= $array_size) {
        $end = $array_size-1;
    } else {
        $end += 500;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I assume the splice operation is also inclusive?

Comment: @Seephor [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) is different: `splice(@source_array, $start_index, $length)`. Needless to say, the `$start_index` is inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a second array of indexes for `natatime` is extremely wasteful.

```
use List::Util qw( min );

for (my $start=0; $start<@array; $start+=500) {
    my $end = min($start+500, 0+@array);
    ...
}
```

Comment: interesting, so does min give the lowest numerical value of the two lists passed? so in the case start+500 exceeds array size, then it returns array size?

Comment: @Seephor, [*Similar to "max" but returns the entry in the list with the lowest numerical value. If the list is empty then undef is returned.*](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util#min)

Comment: @Seephor, The phrase "two lists" is almost never going to make any sense, and it definitely makes no sense how you used it. Two scalars are passed to `min`. (This could also be phrased as "a list of two scalars are passd to `min`".)

Comment: I meant list sizes, but glad you were able to extract the gist.

Comment: @Seephor, That's even worse. If "two lists" makes no sense, neither does "sizes of two lists".

Comment: You are right, list sizes is not correct. I was caught up thinking in terms of context, the indices of the batch size and muddled it with list size. I haven't finished my coffee. The brain is a funny thing and I obviously didn't put much thought into what I was trying to convey. No need to be condescending, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @Seephor Why do you find it "condescending"?  I read down the comments and saw nothing personal. "List" is a subtle notion and your statements were deeply wrong in that sense; ikegami is just straight up letting you know.  (Look up "difference between lists and arrays" (or such); there are a few really informative old SO posts.)  I appreciate it a lot when I'm told clearly that I'm messing up.  Nobody's putting you down here.

Comment: @zdim - they edited what they wrote previously. I think we can all put this comment thread to rest.

Comment: @Seephor OK, I'll monitor this thread and will be quick to remove my comment as soon as that word is gone.